# Como manter tempo uniforme para os slides independente da quantidade de slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Tenho o código abaixo que funciona normalmente.
Porém, com um inconveniente:

***Quanto mais imagens coloco no slide mais rápido as imagens trocam.***

Gostaria de fazer com que, indiferente da quantidade de imagens adicionadas ao slide, elas se tocassem no mesmo tempo!

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slide 8</title>
    <style>
      * {   
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       boder: none;
      }
      body {
       width:1000px;
       margin: auto;
      }
      div.slider {
       width:100%;
       overflow:hidden;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide {
          width:9000%;
       animation:tocaSlide infinite;
      }  
      div.slider ul.slide li {
       width:100%;
       list-style:none;
      }
      div.slider ul.slide li img {
       float:left;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.keyframes.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
    
       var tempoTransicao = 10;
       var quantasImagens = $("div.slider ul.slide li img").length;
       var tamanhoIntervalos = 100/quantasImagens;
       var tempoImagens = 0;
       var t = 0;
       var obj ={ name: 'tocaSlide' };
    
       $("div.slider ul.slide li:first").clone().appendTo("div.slider ul.slide")
    
       for (i = 0; i < quantasImagens; i++) {
    
      tMin = t + tempoTransicao;
      tMax = t + tamanhoIntervalos;
      t += tamanhoIntervalos;
    
      if (i == 0) tMin = 0;
      if (i == quantasImagens - 1) tMax = 100;
    
      obj[tMin + '%'] = { 'margin-left': '-' + tempoImagens + '%'};
      obj[tMax + '%'] = { 'margin-left': '-' + tempoImagens + '%'};
    
      tempoImagens += 100;
    
       }
    
       $.keyframe.define([obj]);
    
       $("div.slider ul.slide").css({
       'animation-duration' : tempoTransicao + 's',
       }).on("animationiteration",function(e){
      $(this).css("animation-delay", "-"+e.originalEvent.elapsedTime/quantasImagens+"s").removeClass("slide");
      void this.offsetWidth;
      $(this).addClass("slide");
       })
    
      });
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slide">
          <li><img src="_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" /></li>
          <li><img src="_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" /></li>
          <li><img src="_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" /></li>
          <li><img src="_imgs/_slideShow/4.png" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tem uma amostra online ou é local?

Comment: Retirei a resposta, mas o problema está em `e.originalEvent.elapsedTime/quantasImagens` que seta o tempo em relação a quantidade de imagens pelo valor em `var tempoTransicao = 10;`... se tem 4 imagens, o tempo será de 2.5, se tem 8 imagens, o tempo cai pra 1.25.. ou seja, quanto mais imagens, menor o tempo de transição em 10s...

Comment: Ok, outro problema que ocorre é que ao chegar no último slide (imagem) a passagem para a primeira novamente não recebe o efeito. A primeira entra abruptamente. Há uma forma de contornar isso?